# How to get value for boolean variable from controller

Tags: apex, controller, boolean

I have a controller where I have this code. I need to pass BooleanVariableName to another controller

```
  PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/ContactV1?id=' + contact.Id);
  pageRef.getParameters().put('BooleanVariableName', 'true');
  pageRef.setRedirect(true);
  return pageRef;
```

In second  controller, I put the following code to get the value for BooleanVariableName. This controller is the conroller for page ContactV1

```
 Boolean  PBV = system.CurrentPageReference().GetParameters().get('BooleanVariableName');
```

When I tried to save it it gave me the following error.
Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to Boolean

Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

All parameters are passed as strings so you will have to do this:

if you are not going to ever call the controller from anon apex and always be in VF context you can do this (sfdcfox):

```
boolean pbv = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('BooleanVariable‌​Name') == 'true';
```

otherwise (Generally not needed and not typically a pattern you should follow as there are other ways to mitigate it)

```
Boolean PBV;

try{
    PBV = boolean.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('BooleanVariableName'));
}catch(Exception e){ //covers not in VF context use case
   PBV = false;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the try-catch: `pbv = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('BooleanVariableName') == 'true';`

Comment: @sfdcfox - You do if testing the controller frrm anon apex....When currentPage is null. But I added this to answer as generally you would not you are right. I just went through this so thats why it was on my mind. I could not debug a controller in VF (SF logs are broken - missing entry points) so I had to call it manually and could not since current page was null.